# Presentation overlay for iOS

Tags: ios, touchesbegan, touchesmoved, first-responder, becomefirstresponder

When I demo my touch apps to remote teams the people on the other end dont know where I am touching. To remedy this, I have been working on an event intercepting view/window that can display touches over applications. No matter how may variations on nextResponder I call, I am unable to react to the touch and pass it along to the controllers underneath. Specifically scroll views dont react nor do buttons.

Is there a way to take an event, get its position, then pass it along to what ever component would have been responding to it initially (the controller underneath)?

**Update:**
I am making some progress with a UIView. The new view is always returning NO to pointInside.This works great for when the touch starts, but it doesnt track moves or releases. **Is there a strategy to adding gesture recognizers to the touch in order to track its event lifecycle?**

Joe

Comment: I don't have a real answer but I note that there's a line in the `UIApplication` docs that says: "*You might decide to subclass `UIApplication` to override `sendEvent:` or `sendAction:to:from:forEvent:` to implement custom event and action dispatching.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more due diligence, I found my oversight. In the layer that was on top and displaying the touches, user interaction needed to be set to false. Once I set that to false, I was able to use that layer for display while catching events on the layers below. The project still isn't done but I am one step closer.

Take care,
Joe

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating your own subclass of `UIApplication` that overrides `sendEvent:`. Your implementation should call `[super sendEvent:event]` as well as process the event as needed.

Update your `main.m` and pass the name of you custom `UIApplication` class as the 3rd parameter to the call of `UIApplicationMain`.